# Как восстановить базу данных из *.MYD *MYI *FRM?

Tags: mysql, linux

У нас упал сайт и хостер предоставил данные файлы для восстановления.

Какие данные, кроме упомянутых файлов, потребуются для восстановления?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Какие данные, кроме упомянутых файлов, потребуются для восстановления?

если все таблицы хранились в вашей базе данных только с использованием движка *myisam*, то перечисленных файлов, по идее, [должно быть достаточно](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html):

> Each MyISAM table is stored on disk in three files. The files have names that begin with the table name and have an extension to indicate the file type. An **.frm** file stores the table format. The data file has an **.MYD** (MYData) extension. The index file has an **.MYI** (MYIndex) extension.

разве что ещё файл `db.opt` потребуется с глобальными для базы данных настройками (типа набора символов по умолчанию и т.п.).

---

все эти файлы хранятся в каталоге, носящем имя базы данных (он расположен обычно в каталоге с данными *mysqld*: часто это `/var/lib/mysql`). вот полное содержимое этого каталога (носящего имя вашей базы данных) вам и потребуется.

скопируйте этот каталог внуть каталога с данными *mysqld* (выставив каталогу и файлам права и принадлежность как у «соседних» баз данных) и перезапустите *mysqld* — сервер после этого должен «подхватить» новую базу данных (она должна быть видна в списке, выдаваемом командой `show databases`).

---

если же хотя бы одна таблица использовала довольно популярный ныне движок *innodb*, то ситуация несколько сложнее. описание таблицы, понятно, хранилось в каталоге базы данных в файле `имя-таблицы.frm`. а вот сами данные таблицы могли храниться в существенно разных местах:

- если глобальная конфигурационная переменная на старом сервере `innodb_file_per_table` имела значение `off`, то данные всех таблиц из всех баз данных хранились в одном файле, и хостер вряд ли его вам предоставит.
- если же эта глобальная переменная была установлена в `on`, то данные для каждой *innodb*-таблицы хранились в файлах `имя-таблицы.ibd` внутри каталога с вашей базой данных.