# Востановить БД после падения mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Я в mysql новичок, извините если будут неточности. 
Главное что меня надо это получить таблицы из БД. Если при полной переустановке mysql база данных не пропадет при том, что никакой экспорт я не делал, то переустановлю mysql. Или может знаете как решить проблему падения, чтобы полуить БД без переустановки. 
Или может можно востановить как то еще ?

```
@asus ➜  ~ rvm:(system)  sudo service mysql start             
@asus ➜  ~ rvm:(system)  sudo service mysql status            
● mysql.service - LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2016-08-21 00:39:23 EEST; 59min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3789 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 21 00:39:23 asus mysql[3789]: .......................................................................................................................................
Aug 21 00:39:23 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:08:47 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:34:58 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:35:15 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:35:40 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:36:46 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:37:33 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:37:34 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.
Aug 21 01:38:41 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/ Stop MySQL Community Server daemon.

@asus ➜  ~ rvm:(system)  sudo mysql -p                        
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
@asus ➜  ~ rvm:(system)  sudo mysql --host localhost --port 3306
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
@asus ➜  ~ rvm:(system)
```

Comment: очень странный вопрос. вы можете его переформулировать? при переустановке база не пропадет.  Можете скопировать файлы базы (в убунте это `/var/lib/mysql/`) данных куда-нибудь, на всякий случай. Если `sudo ps ax | grep mysql` покажет, что сервер запущен, значит, вы просто забыли пароль, погуглите как восстановить его

Comment: @strangeqargo, спасибо помогли

Comment: тогда добавлю ответом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как восстановить базу данных из \*.MYD \*MYI \*FRM?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532088/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-myd-myi-frm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

при переустановке база не пропадет.

Можете скопировать файлы базы (в убунте это /var/lib/mysql/) данных куда-нибудь, на всякий случай.

Если sudo ps ax | grep mysql покажет, что сервер запущен, значит, вы просто забыли пароль, погуглите как восстановить его

Comment: В центосе тоже /var/lib/mysql -- подозреваю, что и в других nix-системах будет что-то аналогичное.

Comment: Нужно уточнить по части myisam или innodb таблиц -- бывают ньюансы, если не дефолтная настройка. Но раз топикстартера устраивает...